# Assigning value in column a based on column b

Tags: vba, matching

I have three values in column F: A; B and c
now,
I want to paste A= yes B= no C= Maybe
If the value matches in the column these results should be the output in column G.
Can you please help?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(CODE(UPPER(F2))-64,"Yes","No","Maybe"),"Not Valid")
```